# Is there a shorthand for {|x| foo x}?

Tags: ruby

I have defined a method that I want to apply to a list:

```rb
class Foobar
  def foo(x)
    x+1
  end

  def bar(list)
    list.map {|x| foo x}
  end
end
```

I was expecting to be able to do something like `list.map(foo)` as it seems rather redundant to create a lambda function that just applies its arguments to a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference the method to pass as a proc with `method`:

```
list.map(&method(:foo))
```

Maybe not the shortcut you're looking for, as it's limited to work with methods that expect only one argument and reduces readability.

Comment: When concerned about readability you could also opt to first save the method in a variable. `foo = method(:foo)` then `list.map(&foo)`.

Comment: The lambda is indeed more readable. (and usable in more cases)

Comment: With lambda do you mean `list.map(&->x { x + 1 })`?

Comment: This works because `method(:foo)` responds to `#call` like a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit more context to the [answer supplied by Sebastian Palma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58187438/3982562).

```
method(:foo)
```

Returns the method `foo` of the current instance (`self`). You can also use this in combination with other instances:

```
(1..10).map(&5.method(:+))
#=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Here `5.method(:+)` returns the `+` method for the instance `5`.